# How Activities are queued if no taskList specified in the code?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

In java sample `HelloActiviy.java`, my workflow method alone configured with taskList named as `HelloActivity`. ActivityMethod doesn't configure a taskList but still, it picked up by the worker which polls the task queue `HelloActivity`

I am wondering how activities are being picked by the worker?

In which queue the activities are queued?

Is it queued under `HelloActivity` taskList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workflow and activity task queues are completely independent. But by default, the same name is used for both of them. So when a workflow is started with the task queue name "foo" the activities that the workflow invokes will be scheduled on the activity task queue named "foo" as well.